# Resource Consumption while serving static Files with a webserver

Tags: apache, http, network-programming, operating-system, webserver

you are running a http server  that is configured to serve static files of the local file system of a multi core server connected to a gigabit network . A handful of clients start requesting the same  8 kb static file . what system resource will be exhausted first ?

1)CPU
2) DISK I/0
3)MEMORY
4) NETWORK
5)OTHER

Reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with network. Reasoning:

1. CPU on a multi-core server should be enough to serve static files over 1 Gbit/s network
2. Disk will be used just once and then we serve the same file form a cache.
3. Memory is not used much either, sincethe file is just 8kb

So the client will be served until we reach the maximum network throughput.

Comment: if the server threshold is  10000 clients  at any  particular moment ,and imagine there are 190000 clients sending request at the same time ( 180000 clients more than the threshold) , on the wire the no of kilo bytes  =  8kb *   (no of clients (10000) ) and never the no of kilo bytes on the wire are  > = 1 gigabyte .  (assuming Tcp Maximum segment size is > 8 kb , the whole static file fits into one packet). after sending the static file .The remaining clients connection are accepted and the process repeats . how can the network exhaust ? [ correct me if i am wrong ]

Comment: @BhuvanMysore There is nothing about the threshold in your question. And even if we add the limit to the equation, still there is nothing to exhaust but the network bandwidth here, because CPU with a limit will be even less busy, disk and memory will be barely used. Sorry, we are just speculating here...

Answer (score 0):

If the same file is served, it will be served from cache memory not from disk.

Memory will be used to handle requests on the web server. So either memory or connection will reach the limit first.

Connection limit 16000 requests per second for 1Gbps connection for 8Kb file.

If you don’t have enough memory then memory will be the first, and even if you have enough memory, connection will be the bottleneck after 16000 connections per second.

For example, if you will have 4GB memory, you can not handle 16000 requests per second.